# Variable value changing without any explicit call

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

In Python 3.0, if I run the following code for a Hangman game

```
secretWord = list("Apple")
compareWord = secretWord
print("".join(secretWord))

for (index , alphabet) in enumerate(secretWord):
    compareWord[index] = "_"

print("".join(secretWord))
```

The result is

```
Apple
_____
```

Why did it change the secret word? I wanted to only modify compareWord so that it went from secretWord to having underscores instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because both `secretWord` and `compareWord` point to the same list.

The first line of code creates a new list from the string Apple, and assigns that list to `secretWord`. The second line assigns this list to `compareWord` - both variables now point to the same list! The for-loop changes each item in the list to an underscore. When printing this list it rightly shows 5 underscores.

If you move the `print("".join(secretWord))` call to after the loop, you will see that the output of that call has also changed to the 5 underscores.

A simple way to fix this is to assign a copy of the list to `compareWord` (that is, a new list but with the same contents of the old one). For exmaple:

- Slicing: `compareWord = secretWord[:]`
- New list call: `compareWord = List(secretWord)`

For some detailed information on how to clone a list in Python, see [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

For some intro on Python and lists, see https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists, this also nicely shows the problem your encountering.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are mutable objects and in following line you are creatign another copy of `secretWord` with name `compareWord`:

```
compareWord = secretWord
```

Therefore when you changes the `compareWord` you are changing the main object which is what that `secretWord` is pointing to.

For getting ride of that problem you need to pass a copy of your list, if it's a 1d list you can use a shallow copy otherwise use `copy.deepcopy`.

```
compareWord = secretWord[:]  # shallow copy
```